# CreateToolhelp32Snapshot produced ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, windows-mobile, windows-ce, out-of-memory

In Windows Mobile 6 Professional Device, I am trying to call the **CreateToolhelp32Snapshot** function, but getting an **ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY** error.

I am already using the flag **TH32CS_SNAPNOHEAPS** as suggested [here](http://nativemobile.blogspot.co.il/2006_01_01_nativemobile_archive.html).
The code is C# .NET 3.5 Compact Edition.

My goal is to find a process by it's name.

```
private const int TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS = 0x00000002;
private const int TH32CS_SNAPNOHEAPS = 0x40000000;
private const int INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = -1;

[DllImport("toolhelp.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(uint flags, uint processID);

public static IntPtr FindProcessPID(string fullpath)
{
    fullpath = fullpath.ToLower();
    IntPtr snapshot_handle = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS | TH32CS_SNAPNOHEAPS, 0);

    if ((Int32)snapshot_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "CreateToolhelp32Snapshot failed.");
```

Thanks.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950978

Comment: Your link refers to a Windows CE 6.0 "Platform Builder" Monthly Update (May 2008). I understand the Platform Builder was a plugin for VS 2005. I am using VS 2008 so it doesn't fit. I also don't see the connection between the Dev Env and the solution. Is it a matter of compilation or DLL version ? Thanks.

Comment: Hans is referring to a fix for a bug in the Windows CE OS itself. The fix refers to a bug in Windows CE 6.0, and you mentioned that your device is using Windows Mobile 6.0, which actually uses Windows CE 5.0, so the underlying bug may not apply in your situation. I don't see anything unusual in the code snippet that you posted. Two things you might want to check: 1) Make sure that you are using `CloseToolhelp32Snaphot` to close the handle returned by `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` instead of `CloseHandle` (probably not causing your issue here) and 2) Verify that `Toolhelp.dll` is on the device.

Comment: Can you verify this happens outside your application? For example, create an empty C# non-gui program with _only_ this code. Do you still get the error?

Answer (score 0):

The only diff to my code seems the hard code process ID in your call to CreateToolhelp32Snapshot:

```
        uint procID = 0;
        IntPtr pHandle = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(SnapshotFlags.Process | SnapshotFlags.NoHeaps, procID);
```

Web page of my CpuMon: http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2012/12/14/mobile-development-a-remote-cpu-monitor-and-cpu-usage-analysis/

full code at: http://code.google.com/p/win-mobile-code/source/browse/trunk/cpumon/ProcessorUsage/CpuMon2/Process.cs